# Unable to start Oracle Virtual Box

Tags: virtual-machine, virtualbox

overflow community,

I need a help on virtual machine issue.

I was working on Oracle VM Virtual Box.it was all working fine.i save state and close it

After some days when i try to access it.
it restore it states but giving an error  as i attached screenshot. and i m unable to access it.

how can i solve this error.what are possible reasons for this

Plz help as i have so  much data and installations on this VM

Thanks in advance
Nisha[image: Error]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try to check the hdd of the vm.

Then if it does not work anyway, you should plug off/on your virtual machine without saving the session.I have read this on this VM thread that maybe can help you.

This error seems to happen when you have saved sessions and update your vbox software.

https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8970

Answer (score 0):

Right button on your virtual machine, Discard Saved State should fix the VM with no data loss